# Get access to Knockout valueAccessor property name

Tags: knockout.js

I need to get the actual name of the knockout viewmodel property bound to a custom knockout binding.  Consider the following custom binding setup...

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" data-bind="myInput: Name" />
```

**Javascript**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myInput = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
    }
};

var viewModel = {
    Name: ko.observable('Knockout')
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Within the context of the update function on the custom binding handler, how can I know the property *Name* is the property being accessed?  I am not seeking the value of Name (which I can get via valueAccessor), but rather the property name itself.

Comment: You'd need to pass in another parameter to your binding handler passing it in.  But this is probably an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you hoping to achieve by knowing the name?  The binding handler should do everything through it's parameters, it shouldn't really be accessing the viewmodel outside of those.

Comment: We have a valid reason for needing to know this.  I posted a very simplified example to keep the question clear and simple.

Comment: in that case, the answer is just `data-bind="myInput: Name, myInputParameter: 'Name'"`, then get hold of it through `allBindingsAccessor`.

Comment: Or just have `myInput` take the name of a property and do the work of both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besided parsing element's `data-bind` attribute or setting property name manually as binding's parameter there's some exotic solution for your problem. Use preprocessing:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myText.preprocess = function(value, name, addBindingCallback) {
  if (typeof(value) !== 'undefined') {
    addBindingCallback('myTextBindedTo', "'" + value.replace(/['\\]/g, "\\$&") + "'");
  }
  return value;
}
```

`ko.bindingHandlers.myText.preprocess` is called for each element with `myText` binding. `value` is value of binding in `data-bind` attribute, `name` is binding name, `addBindingCallback` can be used to add another binding for element.

Now within the context of the `update` function of `myText` binding you can access `myTextBindedTo` using `allBindings`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntc36er2/7/)

[Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html)

**UPD:** added check to the code because `value` can be `undefined` in case of skipping of the binding value:

```
<span data-bind="myText"></span>
```

Comment: Nice - I wasn't aware of this functionality!